# How to deploy Google Cloud Run with static ip address that is already reserved?

Tags: node.js, docker, gcloud

I have a project that is successfully deployed on Google Cloud Run with continuous deployment from GitHub. The application is working fine, my problem is that when each time I update the application, Google cloud assigns the application a new IP address. I want a static IP address each time I update the website on Github and it is redeployed...

I am new to Google cloud. I have checked Google docs and tried to fix it according to docs. I have created a VPC Connector. I have also redeployed a new Revision with VPC Connector but not sure how it works...

Thank you...

Answer (score 2):

You have to configure the VPC egress to send all the traffic through a VPC network that has a Cloud NAT gateway configured with a static IP address.

You have to create a Cloud Router

```
gcloud compute routers create ROUTER_NAME \
--network=NETWORK_NAME \
--region=REGION
```

and then reserve the static IP:

```
gcloud compute addresses create ORIGIN_IP_NAME --region=REGION
```

Then you create the NAT Gateway:

```
gcloud compute routers nats create NAT_NAME \
--router=ROUTER_NAME \
--region=REGION \
--nat-all-subnet-ip-ranges \
--nat-external-ip-pool=ORIGIN_IP_NAME
```

And finally you deploy your Cloud Run service with the command:

```
gcloud beta run deploy SERVICE_NAME \
--image=IMAGE_URL \
--vpc-connector=CONNECTOR_NAME \
--vpc-egress=all
```

Please note that this is still in Beta

Detailed instructions can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip)

Comment: Is there a User Interface way of doing this? I will be thankful for your help :)

Comment: @SaifAliKhan Unfortunately is not possible configure it via WEB UI, but you can use [cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/using-cloud-shell) that have preinstalled the GCloud SDK with this you can use the commands suggested by siamsot

Comment: i followed the instructions but the external server sees the requests coming in with different ip address... what might go wrong? when i go to curlmyip.org in my server, it is showing the external ip that i setup correctly..